# Why is there this Debug in my first package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, package.json

hello world why this Debug ? I new in node .

[why this Debug is there?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFzVU.jpg)

Comment: Because you can start the scripts with the debugger.

Comment: a convenient shortcut placed by vscode.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -2):

You can click that and it will run your script.

Comment: You can click it and it will debug the script. There are other buttons to run them.